# How to connect to postgreSQL in langchain and make schema

Tags: postgresql, langchain

I want to use langchain's SQLAgent with my database PostgreSQL, the default schema is public, I want to use my schema like 'my_schema', what should I do?

I've tried splicing search_path=my_schema after the connection address but I get an error message: no parameters defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two ways for use schema

1. Using search_path like below ([documents](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html))

```sql
SET search_path TO my_schema,public;
```

After set search path using `SHOW search_path;` to show your search path

2. Using schema name behind table or DDL object

```sql
select * from my_schema.table

create table my_schema.test (...)
```